# As root, how do I create a limited FTP user who only has read access to a few folders?

Tags: file-permissions, ftp, user-permissions

I have a website and I have a super admin FTP access. Now, I am in need to share the FTP credentials with others and I wish to give them FTP access in such a way that they could be able to access only few folders and not all the folders.

How can I achieve it?

Xtra details:

I have created a different group 'candidates' and added a user 'testcandidate' into it. Now, my project files are at /home/project/manu/ and I want to give readonly access to the user 'testcandidate' ... I mean when he logs in, he must not change anything. But it should work as usual to 'root' user.

Comment: which FTP server type have you installed on the server? And don't you think its a better idea to chroot(jail) the FTP users in question to restrict access?

Comment: @i.h4d35: I have created a different group 'candidates' and added a user 'testcandidate' into it. Now, my project files are at /home/project/manu/ and I want to give readonly access to the user 'testcandidate' ... I mean when he logs in, he must not change anything. But it should work as usual to 'root' user.... How can I achieve it. Please help

Comment: and say for example in the 'candidates' group, if there is another user called 'test2', do u want a separate set of permissions for that user?